# Error al convertir datetime a string

Tags: c#, windows

Me podrian Ayudar con un error al agregar los datos de una fecha me marca un error de conversion, me marca el error de conversion de date a string, estoy usando windows form, en la base de datos la fecha lo tengo como DATETIME, Es un datepicker, tengo una clase llamada CRN lo cual tengo los datos de fecha

```
public int Insert(CatalogoCRN CatalogoObj)
        {
            SqlCommand cmdInsert;
            string comandosql;
            try
            {
                comandosql = string.Format("INSERT INTO CATALOGO(NUMFACTURA, NAMECLIENTE, NUMPARTE, TIPOMATERIAL, DESCRIPTIONSPANISH," +
                    "DESCRIPTIONENGLISH, CANTIDAD, UNITPRICE, NUMPALLET, OBSERVATION, COUNTRY, FECHAINGRESO) " +
                    "VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')",
                  CatalogoObj.numFactura, CatalogoObj.nameClient, CatalogoObj.numPart, CatalogoObj.tipMaterial,
                  CatalogoObj.DescriptionESp, CatalogoObj.DescriptionUSA, CatalogoObj.quantity, CatalogoObj.UnitPrice,
                  CatalogoObj.numPallet, CatalogoObj.observations, CatalogoObj.country, CatalogoObj.date);

                connectionSql.Open();
                cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(comandosql, connectionSql);
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connectionSql.Close();
                return 1;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex.Message;
                return 0;
            }


        }


 catalog.date = Convert.ToDateTime(catalogTable.Rows[0]["FECHAINGRESO"].ToString());
```

[image: error]

[image: DATE]

```
class CatalogoCRN
    {
        public DateTime date;

        public CatalogoCRN()
        { }

        public void AsignarDatos(DateTime  fecha)
        {
            date = fecha;

        }
```

Comment: Publica el codigo donde se produce el insert.

Comment: perdon, se me habia pasado ahi esta el codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo utilizando `SqlParameter` para que sea el propio servicio quien convierta y ademas te libra de las injecciones sql:

Reemplaza:

```
comandosql = string.Format("INSERT INTO CATALOGO(NUMFACTURA, NAMECLIENTE, NUMPARTE, TIPOMATERIAL, DESCRIPTIONSPANISH," +
                    "DESCRIPTIONENGLISH, CANTIDAD, UNITPRICE, NUMPALLET, OBSERVATION, COUNTRY, FECHAINGRESO) " +
                    "VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')",
                  CatalogoObj.numFactura, CatalogoObj.nameClient, CatalogoObj.numPart, CatalogoObj.tipMaterial,
                  CatalogoObj.DescriptionESp, CatalogoObj.DescriptionUSA, CatalogoObj.quantity, CatalogoObj.UnitPrice,
                  CatalogoObj.numPallet, CatalogoObj.observations, CatalogoObj.country, CatalogoObj.date);

                connectionSql.Open();
                cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(comandosql, connectionSql);
```

Por:

```
 comandosql = "INSERT INTO CATALOGO(NUMFACTURA, NAMECLIENTE, NUMPARTE, TIPOMATERIAL, DESCRIPTIONSPANISH," +
                    "DESCRIPTIONENGLISH, CANTIDAD, UNITPRICE, NUMPALLET, OBSERVATION, COUNTRY, FECHAINGRESO) " +
                    "VALUES(@numeroFactura,@nameClient,@numPar, @tipMaterial,@DescriptionESp,@DescriptionUSA,@quantity,@UnitPrice,@numPallet,@observations,@country,@date)";


                connectionSql.Open();
                cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(comandosql, connectionSql);
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("numeroFactura", CatalogoObj.numFactura));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("nameClient", CatalogoObj.nameClient));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("numPar", CatalogoObj.numPar));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("tipMaterial", CatalogoObj.tipMaterial));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DescriptionESp", CatalogoObj.DescriptionESp));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DescriptionUSA", CatalogoObj.DescriptionUSA));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("quantity", CatalogoObj.quantity));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UnitPrice", CatalogoObj.UnitPrice));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("numPallet", CatalogoObj.numPallet));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("observations", CatalogoObj.observations));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("country", CatalogoObj.country));
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", CatalogoObj.date));
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Es mas codigo, pero mucho mas seguro.