# Error en actualizar en windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

me podrian ayudar en con este error al querer actualizar los datos

```
private void btnactualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int resp;
          asignarDatosObjeto();
          resp = CATCAD.Actualizar(CATCRN);
          if (resp == 1)
          {
              UpdateDGV();
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Imposible conectarse a la base de datos: " + CATCAD.error,
                  "Fallo la conexion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
              this.Close();
          }            
    }




 public int Actualizar(CatalogoCRN CatalogoObj)
     {

        SqlCommand UpdateCad;
          string comandoSql;
          try
          {



            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_ACTUALIZAR", connectionSql);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connectionSql.Open();

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMFACTURA", CatalogoObj.numFactura);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAMECLIENTE", CatalogoObj.nameClient);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMPARTE", CatalogoObj.numPart);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIPOMATERIAL", CatalogoObj.tipMaterial);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTIONSPANISH", CatalogoObj.DescriptionESp);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTIONENGLISH", CatalogoObj.DescriptionUSA);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CANTIDAD", CatalogoObj.quantity);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNITPRICE", CatalogoObj.UnitPrice);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMPALLET", CatalogoObj.numPallet);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OBSERVATION", CatalogoObj.observations);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COUNTRY", CatalogoObj.country);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAINGRESO", CatalogoObj.date);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connectionSql.Close();
                 return 1;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 error = ex.Message;
                 return 0;

             }
        }
```

procedimiento almacenado es algo sencillo

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ACTUALIZAR
@FACTURA VARCHAR(100),
@CLIENTE VARCHAR(100), 
@PARTE VARCHAR(100),
@MATERIAL VARCHAR(100),
@DESCRIPCIONSPANISH VARCHAR(100),
@DESCRIPCIONENGLISH VARCHAR(100),
@CANT INT,
@PRICE FLOAT,
@PALLET FLOAT,
@OBSERVACION VARCHAR(100),
@PAIS VARCHAR(50),
@FECHA DATETIME 

AS BEGIN

UPDATE CATALOGO SET NAMECLIENTE = @CLIENTE,

    NUMPARTE = @PARTE,
    TIPOMATERIAL = @MATERIAL,
    DESCRIPTIONSPANISH = @DESCRIPCIONSPANISH,
    DESCRIPTIONENGLISH = @DESCRIPCIONENGLISH,
    CANTIDAD = @CANT,
    UNITPRICE = @PRICE,
    NUMPALLET = @PALLET,
    OBSERVATION = @OBSERVACION,
    COUNTRY = @PAIS,
    FECHAINGRESO = @FECHA

    WHERE  NUMFACTURA  = @FACTURA
    END
    GO
```

Prueba del almacenamiento en sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: ere]

[image: df]
antes de ejecutar el procedimiento

[image: entes]

despues de ejecutar el procedimiento
[image: ERSF]

Comment: No nos estas dando suficiente información. Trata con el debugger, para que veas el comando de SQL que esta generando (que al parecer llama un Stored Procedure), y corre ese comando directamente en tu BD, muy posiblemente también te dará error.

Comment: Dale una mirada  a esta respuesta que te puede ayudar: [Error al convertir datetime a string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103150/error-al-convertir-datetime-a-string/103157#103157)

Comment: si ya lo hice como el anterior y me dio este error expects parameter which was not supplied mira la actualizacion

Comment: Hola, fíjate que al crear tus parámetros no estás nombrando ninguno con @FACTURA. Puedes mostrar el código de ese procedimiento? Debes crear los parámetros así: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACTURA", Catalog.numFactura); el primer parámetro de este método AddWithValue es el nombre del parámetro en tu procedimiento almacenado, no el nombre de tu propiedad de la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fíjate que al crear tus parámetros no estás nombrando ninguno con @FACTURA. Puedes mostrar el código de ese procedimiento? Debes crear los parámetros así:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACTURA", Catalog.numFactura);
```

el primer parámetro de este método AddWithValue es el nombre del parámetro en tu procedimiento almacenado, no el nombre de tu propiedad de la clase

Comment: Me dices que @FACTURA es el de mi procedimiento almacenado checa la actualizacion, voy agregagr el de mi procedimiento almacenado porque me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Gracias ya pude encontrar la solucion

Answer (score 0):

bueno el error marca un error de sintaxis, verifica los tipos de datos que recibe el procedimiento de almacenado...tu todos los campos los envias con tipo texto por lo que veo...a todos los colocas entre comillas simples

> Call SP_ACTUALIZAR('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')

ACTUALIZADO
------------------------------------------------------------
Intenta ejecutando el procedimiento de esta manera:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_ACTUALIZAR", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("numFactura", numFactura);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nameClient", nameClient);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("numPart", numPart);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("tipMaterial", tipMaterial);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DescriptionESp", DescriptionESp);
...
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: De hecho ya hice una prubea y si me funciono en sql server( EXEC SP_ACTUALIZAR 'USG-N-8', 'PRUEBA','2017', 'TODO', 'DESCRO','DOCE', 3,5,455,'EFE','MEXICO','2017-10-09';
)

Comment: intenta hacerlo de esta forma

Answer (score 0):

intenta poniendo de esta manera:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXEC SP_ACTUALIZAR @CLIENTE, @PARTE,@MATERIAL, @DESCRIPCIONSPANISH, 'DESCRO',@DESCRIPCIONENGLISH, @CANT,@PRICE,@PALLET,@OBSERVACION,@PAIS,@FECHA", conn);

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACTURA", numFactura);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLIENTE", nameClient);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTE", numPart);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATERIAL", tipMaterial);
etc...
```

esto es un ejemplo, no puse las variables en orden correcta ni se si me falto alguna

Comment: Muchas gracias pero me funciono de esta manera                                                                                               
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("
SP_ACTUALIZAR", conn);

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACTURA", numFactura);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLIENTE", nameClient);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTE", numPart);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATERIAL", tipMaterial);